# When using an httpAgent with a single socket, will it wait for a response before sending the next request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I've set my httpAgent to use a single socket (setting it's maxSockets property to 1) and it does use a single socket, I've printed the sockets property on the console and there is really one socket into it.

The problem is: when doing requests, my httpAgent won't wait for the response before sending the next request, is this a normal behavior? Shouldn't it use a single socket for each request?

This is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(d) {
        process.stdout.write('\nresponse');
      });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

    console.log('request ' + (i + 1) + '/256 sent');
}
```

It prints out "request x/256 sent" 256 times and them it prints the response.

I don't want to send a single request at a time, I just want to know if this is the correct behaviour when using a single socket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal because it's asynchronous. The loop will fire all requests and push them to the eventLoop and they will start getting resolved, and you will get the console.logs with the number of requests logged immediately.

Using a single socket is not the same as performing requests synchronously. It's true that all requests will go through the same socket and probably only one at a time will get resolved.

The approach I would follow to fire one request only when the previous has been resolved, is to use promises. Once a promise gets resolved, fire the next one, and so on.

Comment: Thank you!
I don't want to send them synchronously, I just wanted to know if this is how the HTTP agent was really supposed to work.

Your answer was very informative, thank you.